# How to add a element to a new UIViewController on swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11.4

i have been trying to insert a element into my new view controller when this happened: [image]

For those of you who had the image not load, it said Could not insert new action connection: Could not find any information for the class named ProfileViewController. ProfileViewController is the name of the ViewController. Here is my code for the ViewController:

```
import UIKit
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

It was a cocoa touch class with Firebase and Cocoapods. Here is main.storyboard:
[image]

Comment: If you do have your vc class name in storyboard Class field, then I would recommend trying to re-open the vc storyboard file and trying to create IBOutlets once again. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enter the name of your class (`ProfileViewController`) in the "Class" portion of your storyboard? See the image for reference. (This is found on the right pane of Xcode)

Also, I do not see any IBOutlet/IBAction properties in your ViewController which are required for any connection between your storyboard and your code.

If the issue is that you're unable to add an IBOutlet/IBAction, then I would recommend cleaning your project (Product > Clean) and removing DerivedData, then trying again.

[image]